# How to, create proper functioning model dynamically using scriptlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, bootstrap-4

Trying to populate the data into the `modal` form. Also tried putting the `modal` code inside the `for-each` loop and it works fine in displaying the details in the `modal` but the `close button` and clicking outside the `modal` does not work to `close` the `modal`. According to research, should put the `modal` outside the `div` container, placed `model` out, but now it does not work at all. Kindly help me on this.

HTML Code:

```
<% var id %>
<div class="row" >
    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
           <% id = user.userid %>
           <div class="card h-100 justify-content-center">
               <img src="<%= '/uploads/' + user.picpath %>" class="img-thumbnail">
               <div class="caption">
                   <h4><%= user.fname + ' ' + user.lname %></h4>
               </div>
               <p>
                   <button class="myBtn btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myModal<%= id %>">Details</button>
               </p>
           </div>
       </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal<%= id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><%= user.fname + ' ' + user.lname %></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If close button is not working the issue is something else, not related to loop. If you want one modal per user, you should place modal inside the loop.

Comment: Your modal code is expecting id and user, in this case id will always be the id of last user and user will be undefined, as it is outside the for loop. I don't think this is what you wanted

Comment: @AvcS, I already did that but somehow the close button of the modal won't work. If i put back the modal inside the loop would you kindly help me fix the issue why the close button won't work?

Comment: Yes, we should fix the problem close button not working, this has more problems than the actual issue :)

Comment: @AvcS, Is their a way that the button inside the loop would pass its value to the global variable so that i can use it as an id for the modal outside the loop.

Comment: That's where your implementation is wrong, even if you pass id outside the loop, it will be updated on each iteration and you will get only one id which is the id of last user

Comment: @AvcS, ah ok. So the main problem now is the close button and clicking outside the modal to close it is not working. kindly help me fix this.

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 4.0.0 @AvcS

Comment: Got it, your data-toggle on the button should be set to "modal" not  "collapse"

Comment: @AvcS, wow its now working. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you have a few problems in your code

1. `data-toggle` attribute value of the button you are using to open the modal should be `modal` instead of `collapse`.
2. Your modal code is expecting id and user, in this case id will always be the id of last user and user will be `undefined`, as it is outside the for loop. To fix this you have 2 solutions, move modal inside the loop or create modals inside another loop.

**Solution:**

```
<div class="row">
    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <!-- User -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card h-100 justify-content-center">
            <img src="<%= '/uploads/' + user.picpath %>" class="img-thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>
                    <%= user.fname + ' ' + user.lname %>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <p>
                <button class="myBtn btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<%= user.userid %>">Details</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal<%= user.userid %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                        <%= user.fname + ' ' + user.lname %>
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</div>
```